# Angular refresh model on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input, uses the model "filtro3". Clicking on, I want to delete its contents. Doing this works right:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filtro3" placeholder=" Buscar" ng-click="filtro3 = null">
```

But if I want to put the same action in a function does not work:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="filtro2" placeholder=" Buscar" ng-click="actualizaCombo()">

        $scope.actualizaCombo = function() {
           console.log('actualizaCombo');
           console.log('filtro2 before='+$scope.filtro2);
            $scope.filtro2              = null; 
          console.log('filtro2 after='+$scope.filtro2);
        }
```

An execution shown in console:

```
actualizaCombo
filter2 before = undefined
filter2 after = null
```

When I type "as":

```
actualizaCombo
filter2 before = null
filter2 after = null
```

And not erase its contents, on the screen continues to show "as". 
What's wrong? missing something? Thanks

Comment: what do you mean  by "as"?

Comment: The text I entered in the input filter2. Any text, then click and try running the ng-click. Similar tried changing ng-click for ng-change but gives the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your input is inside an angular directive that creates a child $scope, so when you try to reference your $scope.filtro2, it doesn't exist.
It is probably in $scope.$parent.filtro2 or something similar.

As a good practice in angular you should prefer to reference something with dot notation: don't put your filtro2 directly in $scope but use and object like $scope.filters = { filtro2: 'test' }

or, pass by argument the element you want to mutate in your ng-click
ng-click:"myAction(myElement)"

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me an example of how to use $scope.filters to understand?

Comment: simply replace your $scope.filtro2 with $scope.filters = { filtro2: ''} and then in your input bind to  ng-model="filters.filtro2"

Comment: Solution:                     <input type="text" 
                     ng-model="datosEquipos.buscar" 
                        placeholder=" Buscar" 
                     ng-click="clickBuscar()" >   $scope.clickBuscar = function() {
   $scope.datosEquipos.buscar = '';
  }